# how to compare text values between cells in same column and give specific ID(number) in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to create a macro  in excel which can compare text values between different cells in column A and give specific ID in column B. In my sheet there are lots of different data in column A and I also want to compare these data from first row  to last row and assign a same ID(number) to each same text value. Please help me out. I will be happy to hear from you guys. I am trying to show how my sheet will look like my as below....

```
column A  column B
aass       1
aadd       2
ffdd       3
aass       1
aadd       2
aass       1 
ffdd       3
ffdd       3
aadd       2
aadd       2
ffdd       3
aass       1
jjhgf      4
pouwe      5
jjhgf      4
jjhgf      4
qwert      6
pouwe      5
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the following code can help you :
I am just saving data into two dimensional array but before adding the data to array, using a check whether this data already exist in array or not.

```
Sub test()
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set Rng = ws.UsedRange
RowCount = Rng.Rows.Count
Dim dataArr() As Variant
ReDim dataArr(RowCount, 1)
ID = 0
For i = 0 To RowCount - 1
InputText = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value

If Contains(dataArr, InputText) = 0 Then
dataArr(i, 0) = InputText
ID = ID + 1
dataArr(i, 1) = ID
Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = dataArr(i, 1)
Else
Cells(i + 1, 2) = Contains(dataArr, InputText)
End If


Next
End Sub

Function Contains(dataArr, InputText) As Integer
Dim rv As Variant, lb As Long, ub As Long, i As Long
lb = LBound(dataArr)
ub = UBound(dataArr)
rv = 0
For i = lb To ub
    If dataArr(i, 0) = InputText Then
        rv = dataArr(i, 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Contains = rv
End Function
```

Result will be:

[image]

Comment: Dear ,  i am very much thankful to you for giving me the solutions.but unfortunately my data is in not column A  .so what can I do if my data is in column F and ID in column B .Actually I have other data on different column.I just to want to compare the text values in column F and give  ID in column B @raj kamal

Comment: ooo yaaa.its working now.thanks a lot mr. raj kamal.